# How to Get the value of variable inside function in PHP:

Tags: php, function, variables

How to pass the value of `$timeframe` variable from this input code:

```
<input size="2" id="' . $this->get_field_id('timeframe') . '" name="' . $this->get_field_name('timeframe') . '" type="text" value="' . $timeframe . '" />
```

To this function code below:

```
function filter_where( $where = '' ) {
$where .= " AND post_date > '" . date('Y-m-d', strtotime("-$timeframe days")) ."'";
return $where;}
add_filter( 'posts_where', 'filter_where' );
```

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the method of the form submission, you want one of these:

```
$timeframe = $_POST['timeframe'];
```

or:

```
$timeframe = $_GET['timeframe'];
```

To pass it to that function I would suggest modifying the function signature:

```
function filter_where($where = '', $timeframe) {
    $where .= " AND post_date > '" . date('Y-m-d', strtotime('-'.$timeframe.' days')) ."'";
    return $where;
}
add_filter( 'posts_where', 'filter_where' );
```

Comment: I've tried your solution, but it got an error:

        Warning: Missing argument 2 for filter_where()

Comment: Up to you. Superglobals like $_GET or $_POST means that they can be put anywhere in your application, but my taste is to put the definition outside of the function.

Comment: I've tried your solution, but it got an error:

    Warning: Missing argument 2 for filter_where()

Comment: because you're not passing a second argument to it. What exactly are you trying?

Comment: Sorry, for my stupid question, but I just couldn't get the $timeframe to pass its value to the function.

from the input code, I can retrieve the value of $timeframe (using echo($timeframe)), let's say the value is 30.
Then I want to put that value to the function filter_where. I have no idea how to do it.

Comment: `$timeframe = $_POST['timeframe'];var_dump(filter_where($where, $timeframe));`

Comment: still not getting the result, it shows:

    string(29) " AND post_date > '1970-01-01'"